# xml drawable or programmatically made drawable?

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, drawable

So, i just discovered that we can make drawable programmatically. And it got me wondering which one is better in terms of performance and size.

this is how i make drawable programmatically:

```
val badge = GradientDrawable()
    badge.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    badge.setColor(Color.parseColor("#E46868"))
    badge.cornerRadius = 100f
```

and this is the xml version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <solid android:color="#E46868" />
</shape>
```

Both generate same result. So which one should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no big difference in performance.

The advantages of both methods are as follows:

Advantages of xml

1. Easy to reuse views or to bring and write from different layouts.
2. View is separated from logic, making it easy to manage in the long run.
3. Previews give us a preview of which view they represent.

Advantages of drawing with code

1. The view can be flexibly adjusted according to the state of logic.
2. There is no need to create a separate resource file.